# Which variables to use in regression

Tags: probability, statistics, correlation

If I have variables x1,x2,x3,and x4 that have correlation coefficients $-0.9, -0.5, 0.5,$ and $0.9$ to another variable y, what is the effect of choosing different combinations of them in a multivariate regression. Should I not use the negative ones ($-0.9$ and $-0.5$), or should I only use the most strongly correlated (ie $-0.9$ and $0.9$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correlations with $y$ are not enough information for answering the question.
Any linear model that includes one of the $\pm 0.9$ variables has $R^2$ of at least $0.81$.  Without knowing the intercorrelations of the $x$ variables it's not possible to say anything more.

Comment: How could one use the intercorrelations of the x variables to determine the best variables to use in a regression?

Comment: Calculate the R^2 of the model with any subset of the variables.